# Jabra BT2080 Headset stopped working, It paired and connected, shows in sound settings but no sound (just some static)

Tags: sound, bluetooth

The device was working fine yesterday. It got paired and connected and I got sound after selecting it from the settings.

Today the sound is gone. The device still gets paired and connects, the volume buttons are also working but there is no sound although there is some static noise whenever I play something.

I installed blueman an it shows that the device connects successfully.

I installed pavucontrol and it shows only 2 profiles off and HSP/HFP. Currently I have the latter selected.

I even installed stream2ip, it seemed to have connected and audio redirected to the headset but still no sound.

I have killed pulseaudio several times. Reloaded bluetooth module several times. Still nothing.

I am using hp pavillion g6 with broadcom bt chipset running ubuntu 14.01 LTS (also its dual boot with win 8.1). Also I have updated the system yesterday (that could be when the problem started but m not sure).